# Python 2.6 -- paramiko import error

Tags: python, unix, python-2.6, paramiko

I have some scripts that run every 30 minutes in `cron` that import `paramiko`.  Seemingly at random, I will get one of these two errors during import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/packet.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Util/strxor.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Util/strxor.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initstrxor)
```

-- OR --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_ARC4)
```

Every time that I have seen this issue, simply rerunning the script allows `paramiko` to import correctly and the script to finish.

What can cause this issue?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea what may be causing the error, it seems it's failing on the native parts of pycrypto, so you may want to retry a couple of times:

```
from time import sleep
n_tries= 3
import_success= False

while not import_success:
    try:
        from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish, AES, DES3, ARC4
        from Crypto.Hash import MD5, SHA, SHA256, HMAC
        from Crypto import Random
        from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA, RSA
        from Crypto.Util import Counter, number
        import_success= True
    except ImportError:
        if not n_tries:
            raise #re-raise ImportError
        n_tries-=1
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like this, but it's the fallback plan at the very least.  Thanks!